# repeat a process using macro button on multiple columns

Tags: excel

I have two columns **a and b**.

```
a       b
1       1
2       2
3       6
4       7
5       3
6       6
6       9
9       6
```

Now I want to run Descriptive statistics using data analysis tool on column a and I want to repeat the same process for column b.I have created a **macro button**.
I started the macro recording,clicked in data analysis tool for descriptive statistic,specified input range i.e. `$A$1:$A$9` and output range as `$A$11` and stopped macro.

So now my output looks like this in column `$A$11`.

```
a   
Mean    4.5
Standard Error  0.906326967
Median  4.5
Mode    6
Standard Deviation  2.563479778
Sample Variance 6.571428571
Kurtosis    -0.021172023
Skewness    0.40705539
Range   8
Minimum 1
Maximum 9
Sum 36
Count   8
```

I assigned this macro to the button, **but** every time I click the macro button it gives me descriptive statistics for column a and not for b.

I want that when I keep my cursor on `$B$11` it should give me descriptive statistics for column b..

I am a beginner in macro.Please help

Comment: '*I have **two** columns **a, b and c**.*' - Sometimes you can just smell a great question.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
Sub rep()
'
' rep Macro
'

'   This would be your range "(R[-9]C:R[-2]C)"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DATA ANALYSIS CODE HERE"
Range("A10").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B10").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```